# case_when mutate integer conversion issue

Tags: r, shiny, dplyr, case-when

I wonder how to fix the integer and double vector issue in case_when. I need double vector as my numericinput, However, the "case_when" always throws me an error like "x must be an integer vector, not a double vector".

It only allows me to enter integer input when I change "TRUE ~ 0" to "TRUE ~0L"

I need inflation input such as 0.05, 0.01, not integer such as 1,2 3

I've been frustrated with the error for a few days. Can anyone help me on this?

Thanks!

```r
#Load packages
library(shiny)
library(data.table)
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(DT)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'DT'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:shiny':
#> 
#>     dataTableOutput, renderDataTable
library(tidyr)


df<-data.frame('provider'="CVS",  'year'=c(2020,2021,2022,2023,2024,2025))


# Define UI for app that draws a histogram ----
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # App title ----
  titlePanel("Hello Shiny!"),
  
  # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
  sidebarLayout(
    
    # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
    sidebarPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("Brand Inf",
                 numericInput("b1","Brand 1", 0, min = NA, max = NA),
                 numericInput("b2","Brand 2", 0, min = NA, max = NA),
                 numericInput("b3","Brand 3", 0, min = NA, max = NA)),
                
        tabPanel("GFR",
                 numericInput("p1","GFR 1", 0, min = NA, max = NA),
                 numericInput("p2","GFR 2", 0, min = NA, max = NA),
                 numericInput("p3","GFR 3", 0, min = NA, max = NA))),
      width = 2),
    
    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(
      DT::dataTableOutput("table"))
  ))


# Define server logic required to draw a histogram ----
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  DF<-function(var1, var2, var3,var4, var5, var6){
    var1<-enexpr(var1)
    var2<-enexpr(var2)
    var3<-enexpr(var3)
    var4<-enexpr(var4)
    var5<-enexpr(var5)
    var6<-enexpr(var6)
    
    df<-df %>% rowwise %>% 
      mutate(inflation= case_when(year== 2020 ~ !!var1, year == 2021 ~ !!var2, year == 2022 ~ !!var3, TRUE ~ 0),
             GFR=case_when(year== 2020 ~ !!var4, year == 2021 ~ !!var5, year == 2022 ~ !!var6, TRUE ~ 0))
  }
  
  data<-reactive({
    
    DF(input,input$b1,input$b2,input$b3,input$p1,input$p2,input$p3) 
    
  })
  
  #plan awp table
  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DATA <- data()
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Shiny applications not supported in static R Markdown documents

```r
DF(0.05,0.05,0.05,0.01,0.01,0.01)
#> Error in DF(0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01): could not find function "DF"
DF
#> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos): object 'DF' not found
```

<sup>Created on 2020-08-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Are you sure it isn't a problem with your function `DF`?  I think you need to change the arguments like this:
`DF<-function(df,var1, var2, var3,var4, var5, var6)` *note that I added the additional `df` at the beginning.  Additionally, you may need to add `return(df)` to the end.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#Load packages
library(shiny)
library(data.table)
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(DT)
library(tidyr)

df<-data.frame(provider="CVS",  year=c(2020,2021,2022,2023,2024,2025))

# Define UI for app that draws a histogram ----
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # App title ----
  titlePanel("Hello Shiny!"),
  
  # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
  sidebarLayout(
    
    # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
    sidebarPanel(width=2,
     
        h3("Brand Inf"),
        numericInput("b1","Brand 1", 0, min = NA, max = NA),
        numericInput("b2","Brand 2", 0, min = NA, max = NA),
        numericInput("b3","Brand 3", 0, min = NA, max = NA),
        
        h3("GFR"),
        numericInput("p1","GFR 1", 0, min = NA, max = NA),
        numericInput("p2","GFR 2", 0, min = NA, max = NA),
        numericInput("p3","GFR 3", 0, min = NA, max = NA)        
      
    ),
    
    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(
      DTOutput("table"))
  )
)


# Define server logic required to draw a histogram ----
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  DF<-function(var1, var2, var3,var4, var5, var6){
    
    df1<-df %>% rowwise %>% 
      transform(inflation= case_when(year== 2020 ~ var1, year == 2021 ~ var2, year == 2022 ~ var3, TRUE ~ 0),
             GFR=case_when(year== 2020 ~ var4, year == 2021 ~ var5, year == 2022 ~ var6, TRUE ~ 0))
      
    return(df1)
  }
  
  data1<-reactive({
    
    DF(as.numeric(input$b1),as.numeric(input$b2),as.numeric(input$b3),as.numeric(input$p1),as.numeric(input$p2),as.numeric(input$p3)) 
    
  })
  
  #plan awp table
  output$table <- renderDT({
    data1()
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: output]